# Find unique numbers that occur in two different lists

Tags: python, string, set

I have this code:

```
list1 = input()
list2 = input()
unique = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
print(len(unique))
```

and I want to find the unique numbers that occur in both lists. 
However, when I enter the lists [1,2,3,4,5,6] and [6,5,4,3,2,1] it returns 7, instead of 6.

When I edit my code to:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
unique = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
print(len(unique))
```

It outputs 6 correctly. What is going on in my user input code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the inputs are cast to string when using `input`,  and by constructing a `set` you're getting:

```
list1 = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
print(set(list1))
# {',', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'}
list2 = '6,5,4,3,2,1'
set(list2)
# {',', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'}
```

The commas are included, resulting in:

```
list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
# [',', '1', '6', '5', '3', '4', '2']
```

Comment: True. That's the kind of mistake which happens when you use bad variable names (`list1` which is not a `list` at all).

Comment: how would one remove the commas from the count?

Comment: @mcdobae `set(int(x) for x in list1.split(','))`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting your second input to a set.

I'd write it at as the follows:

```
set1 = set(input())
set2 = set(input())
unique = list(set1.intersection(set2))
print(len(unique))
```

Answer (score 0):

input returns a string, and you have to cast or better parse it first.

One option is json, e.g.

```
import json
def parse():
   return json.loads(input())


list1 = parse() #"[1,2,3,4,5,6]" parsed to [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = parse() #"[6,5,4,3,2,1]" parsed to [6,5,4,3,2,1]
unique = list(set(list1).intersection(set(list2)))
print(len(unique))
```

Obviously you could use `eval(input()`, but that could not be considered safe, as it allows executing arbitrary code. Another possible parsing function that does not require brackets could be

```
def parse():
    ip = input()
    return [int(element) for element in ip.split(',')]
list1 = parse() #"1,2,3,4,5,6" parsed to [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```